# Does CompressorHttp2ConnectionEncoder can identify already compressed contents?

Tags: netty, http2, compression

I have implemented a HTTP/2.0 server which supports compression using Netty 4.1.5.Final.[CompressorHttp2ConnectionEncoder](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http2/CompressorHttp2ConnectionEncoder.html) class which is used for HTTP data frame compression. It uses `content-encoding` Transport header field to identify the compression algorithm.

Suppose when I am acting as a transparent proxy, when I obtain an already compressed data frames from backend HTTP/2.0 server (Which has the `content-encoding` header), does the above mentioned class re-compress the already compressed content? If so what is the proper way to use [CompressorHttp2ConnectionEncoder](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http2/CompressorHttp2ConnectionEncoder.html) class so that it would ignore already compressed content.